# Issue with fragment transaction and passing values to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

im having some troubles with FragmentTransaction and passing values from activityA to fragmentA. The problem i think i am having is that i make 2 `new FragmentA()`instances and this breaks `bundle.arguments()` because of the 2 created fragments and i use `if(bundle != null)`in my fragment to check if the bundle is null. Been at this problem for quite some time.

Thanks for help in advance.

This is what i have so far

In this method  i setup my viewpager with 3 fragments(because im using a tabbedlayout)

```
 private void setupViewPager() {
    PagerAdapter fragmentAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_a), new TodoFragment());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_b), new DoingFragment());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fragment_c), new KoncanoFragment());
    ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    TabLayout mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}
```

And this method is used to send a bundle to my FragmentA

```
private void sendToFragToDo(Fragment f, Bundle value) {
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    f.setArguments(value);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, f, "a");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different approach to use to pass data from activity to bundle. Make a method newInstance(Objects you wanna pass as parameters) inside fragment, if you type in AndroidStudio newInstance inside Fragment class it will automatically suggest the implementation for you, if not it will look like this:

```
public static TodoFragment newInstance(data to pass){
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 //then you put into args the data you wann pass with args specific key,value method
 fragment.setArguments(args);
 return fragment;
}
```

In the activity instead of new TodoFragment(), you use TodoFragment.newInstance(data to pass);
To retrieve the passed data you use getArguments(), in Fragment's onCreate()

Comment: I made the method and called TodoFragment.newInsntace(long id) in my activity, because im passing an id to my fragment but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: So you have newInstance(long id){ Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putLong(String key, id);
 fragment.setArguments(args);
 return fragment;} Then on onCreate() you call long id = getArguments().getLong(String key); and does not give you the value?

Comment: Yes, i have     public static TodoFragment newInstance(long id) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putLong("fk",id);
        TodoFragment fragment = new TodoFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }

Comment: And no it doesnt get me the value, do i still keep my old sendToFrag method? because i removed it.

Comment: And onCreate how did you retrieved the data? Also make sure you use newInstace(long id) instead of new Todo Fragment();

Comment: To retrieve the value i used Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
            final long fk_id = bundle.getLong("fk");, i have a question do i still keep my old sendtofrag method? and instead of new TodoFragment i call TodoFragment.newInstance?

Comment: you don't need that method to pass data anymore, but you need the code for the transaction to happen so that the fragment can inflate, meaning that you somewhere in your logic, probably an activity onCreate(), you need to make a fragment manager and a transaction to replace and commit the fragment created with newInstance and the data you want to pass. Also beware you declared fk_id locally, you should declare it in fragment, private long fk_id;

Comment: I will mark the question as answered because it solved my issue with passing data but now i have a new problem, i will update the code above if you could help me a little bit more please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the code is in a fragment's onCreate, I think it should be in onCreateView. Try in onCreate to retrieve the passed data only, and then in onCreateView write that code in an if bassed on the passed data not on the bundle.